# AngularJS localStorage Access

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

Hi I'm learning Angular JS and so far is going well but... I've noticed I have to produce more and more code than normal to do a simple think eg.

I have my setup object:

```
var AppConfig = {
    'defaultEvent' : 'orders',
    'jsonTimeout' : '15000',
    'jsonURL' : 'https://mydomain.com/' + localstorage['myItem']
};
```

so then somewhere within the controller I use some of the objects AppConfig.jsonTimeout. What I don't understand is why something simple like access local storage required additional 3rd module???

Do I have to have some mainController wrapping all other controllers where I have all my variables and this way I can access local storage across the app? What is the simplest practice to do something like example above? is there a way to use HTML5 local storage without 3rd party module?

Thanks

Comment: You don't require any third party module to access localStorage, but it is always good to wrap your access in a service or use a 3rd party module. What is the issue you are facing.

Comment: 1st Where is the 3rd party anything ? 2nd can't you just access `localStorage` as usual ?